# Matches below in espresso

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

Since I have several fields on the registration screen and I use the same string resource for empty fields, how can I get around this error?

```
com.som.android.acceptanceTests.signIn.RegistrationScreenTest > startRegistrationWithEmptyFields[emu_19_WXGA720(AVD) - 5.0.2] FAILED 
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '(with id: com.fentury.android:id/errorMessage and with text: is "This field cannot be empty")' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great resource for Espresso matchers: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/cheatsheet/

Looks like you need something along the lines of:
`onView(allOf(withId(R.id.errorMessage), withSibling(withId(id for particular input))))`

or `isDescendantOfA()` to if it has a unique container view